# Why don't electrons have the same spin even when in same orbit?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrons

Do electrons not have the same spin because that is just how it was found or does it contribute to another factor?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. It is really hard to judge your background and how deep an answer would have to go. Please provide more information [edit]ing your post.

Answer (score 2):

The Pauli Exclusion Principle says no two electrons can have the same quantum numbers, and there are roughly two ways to interpret this.

First, an 'orbital' may host two electrons so long as they have opposite spins.

Second, an 'orbital' may only host one electron, but there is a second orbital that is geometrically and locationally identical which hosts an electron of the opposite spin of the first orbital.

Why?  It is written into the fabric of the universe.  That is how the math works out.  Experiments have strongly supported Quantum Mechanics.